# My Jqplot pie chart is being displayed without any color for the small table inside the pie chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

i am using Jqplot pie chart inside my asp.net MVC 3 web application , but the problem is that the small table inside the pie chart which contains the chart label are being display without any color.
So how i can solve this issue?.
Thanks in advance for any help.
BR

Edited

thanks for ur kind reply, yes i have included these files , but still no colors are shown. here is the code inside my MVC 3 asp.net web application(the pie chart shows two values ;the percentage of students who like a test to the students who did not provide any Rating ).

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [
                 ['Number of Like', @ViewBag.CountRate], ['Other', @ViewBag.other]
                   ];
        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('r1', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
    });
</script>

 <div id = "r1"></div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 1):

jqPlot [documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) doesn't mention it very strongly but it does mention to include the css file

> To use jqPlot include jquery, the jqPlot jQuery plugin, jqPlot css
>   file and optionally the excanvas script for IE support in your web
>   page

So you need to include `jquery.jqplot.min.css` e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css">
```

Also jqPlot recommends using css to customize colors etc see http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotCssStyling-txt.html

Answer (score 0):

are you loading all the required js files? sounds like you are missing:

```
jqplot.pointLabels.min.js
```

add these:

```
("~/scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js")
("~/scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js")
("~/scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js")
("~/scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js")
("~/scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js")
("~/scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js")
```

Comment: thanks; yes i have included these files but still no color will be displayed.